# JavaScript progress bar unhides but won't update

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I want a progress bar to unhide when the button is pressed and then to update. However, with the following code the progress bar shows but does not update.

If I remove `style="display: none"` the bar updates as expected. Any ideas?

```js
document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("progress-top").style.display = 'block';

  var i = 0;
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var width = 1;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 50);

    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar').item(0).setAttribute('aria-valuenow', width);
        document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar').item(0).setAttribute('style', 'width:' + Number(width) + '%');
      }
    }
  }


})
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="display: none" id="progress-top">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4 for the CSS

```
.progress {
  display: flex;
  height: $progress-height;
  overflow: hidden; // force rounded corners by cropping it
  font-size: $progress-font-size;
  background-color: $progress-bg;
  @include border-radius($progress-border-radius);
  @include box-shadow($progress-box-shadow);
}

.progress-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  color: $progress-bar-color;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: $progress-bar-bg;
  @include transition($progress-bar-transition);
}
```

Comment: I made you a  stacksnippet. Please [edit] it and make it a [mcve] with relevant HTML and frameworks

Comment: Your code runs when you add a button and you add some basic CSS. So we need to see what you are doing that is not making it work. So your question needs more code.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap progress bar. When I use the code below it works but for some reason, it doesn't work with the Bootstrap progress bar. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using the [`<progress>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress) were you just need to se the `value`.

To prevent starting the loop twice, consider checking the PID.

```js
let id = null;

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("progress-top").style.display = 'block';
       
    if (id === null) {
        var val = 1;
        id = setInterval(frame, 50);

        function frame() {
            if (val >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
                id = null;
            } else {
                val++;
                document.getElementById('progress').setAttribute('value', val);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.progress {
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress" style="display: none" id="progress-top">
    <progress id="progress" value="0" max="100">0%</progress>
</div>

<button id='submit-btn'>Click me</button>
```

---

Regarding the Bootstap variant, you'll need to set both `style.width` and `innerHTML`.

The `aria-valuenow` doesn't need to be updated.

```js
let id = null;

document.getElementById("submit-btn").addEventListener("click", function() {

    document.getElementById("progress-top").style.display = 'block';
       
    if (id === null) {
        var val = 1;
        id = setInterval(frame, 50);

        function frame() {
            if (val >= 100) {
                clearInterval(id);
                id = null;
            } else {
                val++;
                document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].style.width = val + '%';
                document.getElementsByClassName('progress-bar')[0].innerHTML = val + '%';
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```css
.progress {
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="progress" id="progress-top" style="display: none">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>

<button id='submit-btn'>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! however when I use the bootstrap progress bar using the suggested amendments it doesn't work, any ideas?

Comment: I've updated my answer with another snippet showing the bootstrap bar. Hope this helps!